# How to call the JQuery function from inside the DIV element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<html>
<h1>animationComplete</h1>
<div class="red">   
    <div id="tile1" class="live-tile" data-initdelay="4500" data-delay="2500" data-mode="flip">    
        <div><p>This will be replaced with items from the hidden &lt;ul&gt; with the class 'itemsSource'
           <span class="tile-title">First Tile</span>
           </p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>
                item content will be here
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- im using a ul here, but this pattern can be used with div, p, span etc. -->
    <ul class="itemsSource">
        <li>Some content to use 1</li>
        <li>Some content with a title to use 2
            <span class="tile-title">look a title!</span>
        </li>
        <li><p>Some content in a &lt;p&gt; to use 3</p></li>     
        <li>Some content to use 4</li>
        <li>Some Content to use 5</li>
    </ul>
</div>
</html>      
<script>
var $item = $(".itemsSource>li").first();
//set the back tile to have content of the first item by default
$("#tile1>div").last().html($item.html());
//set up tile
$("#tile1").liveTile({
    pauseOnHover: true,
    animationComplete: function(tileData, $front, $back) {
        //get the next item from the list or the first
        $item = $item.next("li");
        if ($item.length == 0)
            $item = $(".itemsSource>li").first();
        $back.html($item.html());

    }
});
</script>
```

I am trying to fetch all the records from the database using Json. for each record the "#tile1" div is added dynamically  with  consists the data for the record.I want to call the function for each tile to load and access the details contained in the list. Can anyne help how to call the function for each div

Here is my code that dynamically creates the tile for each record 
   Click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/drewgreenwell/9w98S/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=9w98S) to see the tile animation

```
function showMessages(profiles) {
    for (var i = 0; i < profiles.length; i++) {
        var message = profiles.offers[i];

        $('div.red').append(
            $('<div/>')
            .attr({
                id: message.username,
                class: "live-tile",
                mode: "flip"
            }).append($('<div/>').append($('<p/>').text(message.user.email))
                .append($('<span/>').attr({
                    class: "tile-title"
                }).text(message.username))));

        $("div#" + (message.username)).append(($("<div/>").append($("<p/>"))));
        var list = $("div#" + (message.username)).append($('<ul/>').attr({
            class: "itemsSource"
        })).find('ul');


        list.append(($("<li/>").text(message.full_name)));
        list.append(($("<li/>").text(message.mobile)));
        list.append(($("<li/>").text(message.currentcity)));


    }
    loadtile();
}
```

Comment: what function are you talking about?

Comment: Invalid markup. Elements can be placed only in the body.

Comment: your script element must be within the html element. Also it's unclear how the `showMessages` relates to the rest of it? What's its purpose and where is/should it be called from? Lastly, you say "I am trying to fetch all the records from the database using Json". There's no evidence of this in your code. Again, in what way is this relevant?

Comment: . $("#tile1").liveTile,  I am asking about how to pass the function for each tile.. I tried to give a unique  DIV ID attribute name for each record by appending their username to the element id. Thanks in Advance @Maurice Perry

Comment: Please check here for the example demo. http://jsfiddle.net/drewgreenwell/9w98S/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=9w98S ThankYou. @ADyson

Comment: so what's the flow? You download the records from the server. Is this via AJAX? Then you run `showMessages` on the records? Then what? You want to turn these records into live tiles? At the moment, your liveTile function runs when the page loads (or it would, if it was within the `<html>` element), but I'm guessing your tiles don't exist at that time, because you haven't loaded them from ajax?